# UPDATE database with pandasql

Tags: python, sql, pandasql

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

datos = pd.read_csv('datosactividad.csv')

def Reservar():
    dataA = datos
    print(ps.sqldf(("UPDATE %s SET Seats = '2' WHERE ID = 1"%dataA), locals()))


Reservar()
```

However, it returns this error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "Airline": syntax error`

This is my database:

```
ID,Airline,Origin,Destination,Flight,Departure,Duration,Arrival,Seats
1,American,MIA,IAH,AA99,09:50,04:00,13:50,4
```

Guys, could you help me?

Comment: Please refer to show database in text instead of link

Comment: Okay. I already have done.